# Setting <style> block to disabled

Tags: html, css

How can I disable a style block?

```
<style disabled="true">
    progress {
        background-color: rebeccapurple;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 9px;
        height:25px;
        width:300px;
    }
</style>
```

the above doesn't seem to work, is it possible to do it this way? Or do I need to disable it programmatically?

Comment: Why are you trying to disable a (mostly, and usually) non-interactive element? What's the goal that you thought the `disabled` property/attribute might solve?

Comment: @AlexChar To clarify, `disabled` is not a valid content attribute, but is a valid IDL attribute (property).

Comment: @AlexChar: `disabled` is a property of `HTMLStyleElement`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement

Comment: A much more common way to do this is to add/remove a class on the element you're targeting... so your rule might instead be `progress.active {...}`; and if your styles are in a separate CSS file (like mine _always_ are) there are no `<style>` blocks to disable.

Comment: There is something not right. The mdn link, earlier, says "disabled" is true if it's enabled and false if it's not which implies, to me, this is a read only attribute. It's also under Web APIs. I'm not sure this is valid HTML markup here. In fact, the validator flags it as an error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is about invalid HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <style id="switch">
 body{ 
    background-color: gray;
 }
 </style>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.button').click(function(){
        document.getElementById("switch").disabled=true;
    });
 });
 </script>

<html>
    <body>
    <a href="#" class="button"><button>Button</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Setting an id to the style tag will control specific css. You can re-enable it by changing disabled back to false. Hope that works.

Comment: Can you provide a citation for this?  I never knew disabling a style element would turn its rules off!

Comment: @StephenP See [HTMLStyleElement.disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#dom-style-disabled), [LinkStyle.disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#dom-linkstyle-disabled) and [StyleSheet.disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-StyleSheet-disabled).

Comment: Sorry I didn't have a reference on hand. I've used this trick long ago to force off css for print mode. It also works on external css files. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp) see example 2.